# Set spark.local.dir to different drive

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I'm trying to setup standalone Spark on Windows 10. I would like to set `spark.local.dir` to `D:\spark-tmp\tmp`, as currently it appears to be using `C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp`, which in my case is on an SSD drive which might not have enough space given the size of some datasets.

So I changed the file `%SPARK_HOME%\conf\spark-defaults.conf` to the following, without success

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               file:/D:/spark-tmp/log
spark.local.dir                  file:/D:/spark-tmp/tmp
```

I also tried to run `%HADOOP_HOME\bin\winutils.exe chmod -R 777 D:/spark-tmp`, but it didn't change anything.

The error that I get is the following:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temp directory (under file:/D:/spark-tmp/tmp) after 10 attempts!
```

If I start the path with `file://D:/...` (note the double slash) nothing changes. If I remove the scheme at all, a different exception says that the scheme `D:` is not recognized.

I also noticed this warning:

```
WARN  SparkConf:66 - In Spark 1.0 and later spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).
```

So I tried to put the following line in `%SPARK_HOME%\conf\spark-env.sh`:

```
SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=file:/D:/spark-tmp/tmp
```

If I put this line and comment the `spark.local.dir` line in the `.conf` file, Spark works perfectly, but the temporary files are still saved in my `AppData\Local\Temp` folder. So the `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` line is not read.

What's strange is that, if I let it run, it actually puts logs in `D:/spark-tmp/log`, which means that it's not a problem of syntax or permissions.

Comment: Make it an environment variable SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS with value d:\spark-tmp\tmp

Comment: @sramalingam24 it worked, thanks! If you make this into an answer, I'll accept it. I don't know why I didn't think about setting an environment variable in Windows.

Comment: cool, no problem. I added it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On windows you will have to make those environment variables

Add the key value pair

```
SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS -> d:\spark-tmp\tmp
```

to your systems environment variables