# Setting up spark.local.dir in Spark Shell

Tags: apache-spark

I'm pretty new to using spark shell. I'm trying to set one up but I need some help with the configurations.
For:

```
--conf spark.local.dir = ...
```

What should I be using as the directory for that configuration? Am I supposed to use a local directory on my computer or some directory on a cluster?

Comment: Where are you setting this up? Whatever path you give here, the directory will be created on the node where the driver will be running

Comment: I’m setting this up as a Spark shell runner script. I see, so it doesn’t have to be an existing directory?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't necessarily have to be an existing directory. Check this if you are setting in your local Windows machine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52917761/set-spark-local-dir-to-different-drive
Also, you need to pass this conf when you are calling spark-shell, because it should be done before creating spark-shell